# Filling database randomly

Tags: sql-server, database

I need to generate my sql server 2005 database for testing a multithreaded application. It must be more than 3 gb at least.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [SQL Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Generator/index.htm).